# What's the right way to unit test a read-only model in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unit-testing

I have a mysql view in a Laravel project. I've written some reports against the view.

How do I seed the model in my unit tests? I have the model annotated as readonly, so I can't seed the data the normal way.

Here's my model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Model;
use MichaelAChrisco\ReadOnly\ReadOnlyTrait;

class FancyView extends Model
{
    use ReadOnlyTrait;
    protected $table = 'really_fancy_view';

}
```

I have a mysql view that gets created in a migration.

One idea we had was to seed the tables the view uses, then run create the view. But is this the right way to test against a mysql view? My view is created with raw SQL. Will Laravel be able to handle creating a view in a test environment?

I can't find anything online about testing against a view, let alone anything on SO.

Comment: I don’t know what $vertical and $query are, but I think I’d be looking at passing mocks to scopeVertical().

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, possibly, is create a folder in your tests with your gold set of data (be it sql insert files or csv's) and then just read in and run those against the database before running the tests (you may be able to leverage a migration as well, but I am personally not familiar with them in laravel).

You can leverage `setUpBeforeClass` in phpunit to accomplish this. Drop the test table if it exists before you read in the contents of your golden set and insert it into the database. Then use `tearDownAfterClass` to drop the table again after the tests have occurred.

This pattern can also be used for your proposed second solution, seeding the data into the source tables (only enough data to run the test efficiently) then create the view in the same step.

```
class DatabaseTest extends TestCase {
    public function setUpBeforeClass() {
        // make sure you're starting with a fresh state
        $this->tearDownAfterClass();
        // 1. seed database tables
        // 2. run view generation query
    }

    public function tearDownAfterClass() {
        // 1. drop view table
        // 2. truncate seeded data
    }
}
```

As for which is better, that really depends on what you're trying to test. Are you testing that the database can actually create the view? If so then it would make sense that you test that the view was able to be created at all. A benefit of this would be knowing that if the view somehow broke your tests would catch it right away.

Performance concerns shouldn't be an issue, because you should only be testing against enough data to verify that your view is being composed accurately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to test that my report is built properly, that I'm bringing back the right info. So, I want to know what's in the view, then make sure that I'm pulling the right info

Comment: As long as you have a subset of data that has a knowable and accurate outcome, then you can use that as the baseline for your tests. You run the migration to populate the tables for the test, build the view and then run the tests afterwards. Just be sure to tear down/remove the data when the tests complete so the test is isolated each time.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you do not need to unit test something that is fully tested in the library: 
https://github.com/michaelachrisco/ReadOnlyTraitLaravel/blob/master/src/ReadOnlyTrait.php

If you were so inclined, you could make the table and populate it with faked data just as jardis suggested.

If you are looking to test views (or full on integration tests) within Laravel, you can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk which looks to be a wrapper around Selenium.